How to limit the long text area field in page layout
I have concern with long text area field in Salesforce. When I approach long text value in one of Page Layout from Object it's show all inserted text, which is not good because user want to see other values on that dashboard detail (more readable).

Previously I have tried with abbreviate() method, but its remove all text and only show based on parameter from that method.

What approach do I need to do to display a few texts/lines but when text is clicked, it will display all values?
